# How to Encode image.RGBA data to rtp packet using h264 codec in pion webrtc golang

Tags: go, webrtc, codec, rtp

I have a stream of image data coming in from a ros topic subscription. I am converting that data in to an golang image format which is (image.RGBA). I want to encode this data and write as sample to pion webrtc video track.
I Tried using gen2brain x264 codec but it failed due to higher memory allocation.
Please guide the correct way of doing it. Also should I have to encode the image first before writing the sample or does pion automatically encodes the data. I don't really know.

Here is my implementation

```
sub, err := h.Subscribe(cam.TopicName, func(msg *sensor_msgs.Image) {
            throttler(func() {
                width := int(msg.Width)
                height := int(msg.Height)
                data := msg.Data
                rect := image.Rect(0, 0, width, height)
                newImage := image.NewRGBA(rect)
                for i := 0; i < (3 * width * height); i += 3 {
                    modifiedColor := color.RGBA{
                        R: data[i+0],
                        G: data[i+1],
                        B: data[i+2],
                        A: 255,
                    }
                    newImage.Set((i/3)%width, (i/3)/width, modifiedColor)
                }

                
                
                if err = videoTrack.WriteSample(media.Sample{Data: <Data Here>, Duration: time.Second}); err != nil && err != io.ErrClosedPipe {
                    panic(err)
                }
                
            })

        })
```

Comment: Well I think the "normal" way would be to just encode it as a jpeg/png send it as bytes, and then decode on the other side. I don't think people normally send structs/interfaces around. Failing that, maybe you could use `encoding/gob`. Never tried it myself though.